# Issue with custom created fritzing part

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, fritzing

I have created a custom part, starting from a generic DIP 8 IC.
I have increased the width of the component using inkscape, but now I have this situation where the connection points / terminals are not shifted properly to the right. I guess these are still in the original location.

How can I fix this?
I have now modified the svg file in 
C:\Users[username]\Documents\Fritzing\parts\svg\user\schematic\MCP2551_25828293fcd6bb68e17b63fa536d7d1d_3_schematic.svg

In what file are these terminals described?

[image]

Comment: [Have you considered not using Fritzing?](https://hackaday.com/2016/10/11/creating-a-pcb-in-everything-friends-dont-let-friends-use-fritzing/)

Comment: +1 @HarrySvensson. If you're investing time in creating custom library parts for Fritzing, it's not a big jump to invest time in a tool that will benefit you in the long run. Fritzing is a nice demonstration tool, but it has a lot of limitations (if your intent is to design a PCB).

Comment: @DanielGiesbrecht can you please advice any user friendly tool?

Comment: @mvermand all tools have a learning curve (some worse than others). The Hackaday post that Harry linked to provides a nice breakdown of different tools. Personally I'd recommend researching KiCad, Eagle, CircuitMaker, and Diptrace, and trying them out. They all have good communities with lots of resources to help get you started. The EEVblog forum also has [threads](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/eda/) for help with different CAD packages.

Comment: @mvermand My classmates recommended me Eagle, I tried it and thought my classmates had pranked me. Because Eagle drives me nuts. - I looked at Fritzing but noticed that... it felt like I was using paint rather than photoshop. Not... professional enough. - Then I came across KiCad and it's great. When I attended the university I was forced to use "NI Circuit Design Suite" which was great. But KiCad has smoother workflow. I recommend KiCad foremost and NI Circuit Design Suite.  KiCad is free.